# How to remove Clear button on Autocomplete and show only text

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, material-ui, react-virtualized

I'm new to react-virtualization and Autocomplete. I have currently build a list which shows multiple texts when the checkbox is selected. Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-1qzd3?file=/demo.tsx

I want to show only one text when anything is selected from the list and also remove the clear button and grey background attached to it.

Answer (score 48):

There is a dedicated prop to disable the Icon.
try the prop `"disableClearable"` on the Autocomplete component
it is here in the documentation:

```
<Autocomplete
    {...defaultProps}
    id="disable-clearable"
    disableClearable
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="disableClearable" 
    margin="normal" />}
/>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it prevents the clearing behavior at all.  If you just want to remove the X icon because of space constraints there doesn't seem to be a 'proper' way to do it at the moment - I ended up using CSS to hide the class .MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator and descrease the rightPadding on..MuiInput-root

Comment: You can pass `closeIcon={null}` as a prop to disable close icon

Comment: doesn't work in freeSolo mode

Answer (score 5):

Controlled MuiAutocomplete with typescript and setting `disableClearable={true}` can lead to an error in type checking (Error: value should be T or undefined).

This happened to me when my controlled value type definition was T | null.

In this situation just `disableClearable={value !== null}` solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this in Material UI V5 and using `freeSolo`.

You have to add `disableClearable={true}` to `Autocomplete` and then you should remove `type:text` from `Textfield`.

You should have something like this.

````
<Autocomplete
  disableClearable={true}
  freeSolo
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      placeholder={placeholder}
    />
  )}
  name="input"
/>```
````

Comment: I am able to remove cross icon by using this.  Jsut to clarify add 
type: 'text'    at input props of TextField:

InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              type: 'text',
              ...............
    }}

Answer (score 1):

As of MUIv5 Autocomplete isn't in lab anymore and does things a bit different and gives you more customization on the display.  Both the clear icon and the downarrow are in the InputProps.endAdornment that is passed into the renderInput function.  So you can remove it before spreading to to TextField

```
 <Autocomplete
  options={options}
  renderInput={params => {
    const InputProps = { ...params.InputProps };
    InputProps.endAdornment = null;
    return (
      <TextField    
        {...params}
        InputProps={InputProps}
      />
    );
  }}
  openOnFocus  
  />
```

Note how InputProps is after the {...params} spread.

If you do this you'll need to add 'openOnFocus' prop since the downarrow won't be there to click to open the autocomplete.

MUI also adds some paddingRight to .MuiInput-root class to make some space for the clearIcon and downArrow, so if you're tight on space you might need to remove those, I ended up using an !important css rule on the TextField class, but we're still using the old JSS way.  Not sure what the proper emotion styling way to do it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";
import { ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBox";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { List } from "react-virtualized";
import faker from "faker";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

const ListboxComponent = React.forwardRef(function ListboxComponent(
  props,
  ref
) {
  const { children, role, ...other } = props;
  const itemCount = Array.isArray(children) ? children.length : 0;
  const itemSize = 36;

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <div {...other}>
        <List
          height={250}
          width={300}
          rowHeight={itemSize}
          overscanCount={5}
          rowCount={itemCount}
          rowRenderer={(props) => {
            return React.cloneElement(children[props.index], {
              style: props.style
            });
          }}
          role={role}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

const myDAta = Array.from(new Array(10000)).map(() => {
  return { name: faker.name.findName() };
});

myDAta.unshift({ name: "ALL" });

export default function CheckboxesTags() {
  const [selectedFilm, setSelectedFilm] = useState([]);
  const onCloseHandle = () => {
    console.log("Closed");
  };
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      ListboxComponent={ListboxComponent}
      options={myDAta}
      onChange={(e, film) => {
        console.log(e.target);
        setSelectedFilm(film);
      }}
      onClose={onCloseHandle}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      // fullWidth
      renderOption={(option) => <>{option.name}</>}
      closeIcon=""

      style={{ width: 300, maxHeight: "1px" }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Checkboxes"
          placeholder="Favorites"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "All", year: 0 },
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 }
];
```

Comment: This just hides the close icon which I'm fine with. But how to remove the close icon and grey background surrounding the text? @Priyanka Panjabi

Comment: This will allow you to make only a single selection at a time without close icon and background . Do you want to add multi selection ?

Comment: I'm doing multiple selections with checkboxes as I shared the sandbox link. So yes, I will want to do it for multiple selections with checkboxes @Priyanka Panjabi

Comment: But you have mentioned it "I want to show only one text when anything is selected from the list"

Comment: Yes. So if there are checkboxes and multiple selections then I should show only the first one selected and not others and with no close button and background. Just the text. Sorry for my line. Its selection from multiple data.

Answer (score 0):

Return all params, without `endAdornment` in `TextField`

```
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} 
InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, endAdornment : null }}
onPaste={handlePaste} variant='outlined'/>}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use **disableClearable** property to enable or disable the clear icon in the auto complete.

```
<Autocomplete
    {...defaultProps}
    disableClearable={true/false}
/>
```

where

disableClearable - true (clear icon will be disabled)

disableClearable - false (clear icon will be enabled)