# MUI Autocomplete component showing two clear buttons in Chromium. How to hide both?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, autocomplete

The second clear button shows only on Chromium; it doesn't show on Firefox.

[Example of a MUI React Autocomplete component showing two clear buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hHAy.jpg)

[All the solutions mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209544/how-to-remove-clear-button-on-autocomplete-and-show-only-text) hide only the right most button, not the one on the left.

How do I hide the one on the left?

This seems to happen only when `type: 'search'` is added to `InputProps`

Minimal, reproducible example on Chromium Version 110.0.5481.100:

```
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  disableClearable
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={supported_games}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: 'search'}} />}
/>
```

[image: Reproducible outcome:]

Comment: Is this a bug from MUI? Can you provide a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: @konekoya Added. I don't know if it's a bug, which is why I haven't started a Github issue, but I noticed the second clear button shows up when I involve `InputProps` If `InputProps` is taken out of the example code, it works as intended. Edit: It seems to be `type: 'search'` making it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Should be the default style from input `type="search`", add this to your TextField `sx` props:

```
sx={{ "input[type='search']::-webkit-search-cancel-button": {
     display: "none",        
   }
}}
```